# Excel file semi-structured data conversion to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a dataframe that looks like this

| aaa | ddd | Mond. Friday | Sat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bbb | ddd | 8-20 | 7-21 |
| ccc | ddd | 9-21 | 10-19 |

And I would like to transform something like below

| aaa | ddd | day of the week | Open | Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bbb | ddd | Monday | 7 | 21 |
| ccc | ddd | Thrusday | 10 | 19 |

thanks advanced

Comment: You should add some explanation regarding the expected output. How does `day of the week` calculated along with Open and Close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by manipulating the date and then spitting the next column using pandas.str.split()

```
df['day of the week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Mond. Friday'], format='%m-%d', errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%A')
df[['Open','Close']] = df['Sat'].str.split('-', expand=True)
df.drop(['Mond. Friday', 'Sat'], axis =1, inplace=True)
```

**output -**

```
   aaa  ddd day of the week Open Close
0  bbb  ddd          Monday    7    21
1  ccc  ddd          Friday   10    19
```